# How to type hint a variadic function that returns its arguments in Python

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typing

I'm trying to create a function that can be used as an annotation (to later inspect the function and do stuff with the expected return values...)

```
def WillReturn(*kwargs):
    # dark magic
    return kwargs
```

Question is: how do I annotate WillReturn in such a way that the type hinter will give the following warnings?

```
def MyFunction(a, b, c) -> WillReturn(int=1, str='yo'):
    return (123, 
            1.2,  # error! expects a str at position #1
            None) # error! expects two values
```

## Idea 1:

This would do the trick but is not quite scalable:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F = map(typing.TypeVar, 'ABCDEF')
@typing.overload
def WillReturn(A) -> A: ...
@typing.overload
def WillReturn(A,B) -> (A,B): ...
@typing.overload
def WillReturn(A,B,C) -> (A,B,C): ...

# and so on and so forth
```

## Idea 2:

subclass from typing.Tuple or use _VariadicGenericAlias directly, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the intended usage of either object.

Comment: Hm... interesting question. It looks like [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) may be of interest to you, although I'm not sure it directly solves your problem (`ParamSpec` may be difficult to convert to `Tuple`, oddly enough). But it may serve as some inspiration

Comment: Very soon, type hints will not be evaluated at run-time at all. What's wrong with `Tuple[int, str]`?

Comment: @chepner The reason why Tuple[int, str] is not an option is that the arguments passed to WillReturn are not generic types but, for example, namedtuples, dataclasses, marshmallow models...
I am aware of the soon-to-be-coming changes to typing, I'm hoping the conversation sparked by FastAPI will result in some future-proof way of doing this.